# JSF (Primefaces) Открыть диалог при загрузке страницы (по условию)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Требуется при загрузке страницы проверять некое условие и, если истинно, открывать диалог. Все примеры, какие нашел, показывают, открытие диалога по нажатию на кнопку или при безусловном открытии. Использую следующий код

```
<c:if test="#{sB.isChangePassword == true}" >
   <script>
       jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          "PF('dlg').show();"
       });
   </script>                    
</c:if>     

<p:dialog id="dlg" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false"> ... </p:dialog>
```

но не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойство visible у p:dialog:

```
    <p:dialog header="Warning" visible="#{sB.changePassword}">
        You need to change password!
    </p:dialog>
```

Обратите внимание на то, что обычно в EL опускаются префиксы свойств `get/set/is`